# How to exclude dependency of wsdl4j in axis1.4 as it is affecting the application not to work by throwing InovcationTargetException

Tags: maven, pom.xml, axis, wsdl4j

Caused by:

> java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class com.ibm.wsdl.DefinitionImpl does not implement the requested interface javax.wsdl.extensions.AttributeExtensible

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create an [MCVE].

Comment: Sorry. Container is already having wsdl4j-1.6.2.jar. I have observed that when I have written only axis1.4 dependency code in my pom.xml, it automatically downloading axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar file which is also creating problem to my existing application. how to remove this internal dependency.

Comment: Please update your question with this information.  Read [ask] and take the [tour].

Answer (score 1):

The reason for `axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar` getting downloaded when you try and build using `axis:1.4` in your project is that it is [defined within dependency for the artifact itself.](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Caxis%7Caxis%7C1.4%7Cjar).

If you don't want to download `axis-wsdl4j-1.5.1.jar`, you can exclude it from your project by making following changes to your pom.xml -

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
         <groupId>axis</groupId>
         <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
         <version>1.4</version>
         <exclusions>
             <exclusion>  <!-- declaring the exclusion here -->
                 <groupId>axis</groupId>
                 <artifactId>axis-wsdl4j</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
         </exclusions> 
   </dependency>
   <!--...other dependencies -->
<dependencies>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but this i have already tried and still facing the same error. Any other pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Luckily, the above error got solved, but i ended up the below error while trying to login to my application. I am using CXF 2.1.1 jar.

Comment: org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain doIntercept
INFO: Interceptor has thrown exception, unwinding now
org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: Error writing to XMLStreamWriter.
 at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.writeSoapEnvelopeStart(SoapOutInterceptor.java:136)
 at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:76)
 at org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.interceptor.SoapOutInterceptor.handleMessage(SoapOutInterceptor.java:57)
 at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.

Comment: @newtostack12 that seems to be a different exception and should be raised in another thread. Also note that this could be an error thrown because of you implementation, I would suggest to debug first and then ask the same in another question. Thanks

Comment: I couldnt debug as it is something to do with the jar involvement in between.So, kindly check and let me know if you can point me to the missing thing.

Comment: @newtostack12 Would suggest sharing the complete details of the new exception in a new question to get it resolved.